# RegEx code accepting digits XXXX.XXX or XXXX.XX or XXXXX

Tags: regex

I'm currently working with the regex to only allow users to input digits `xxxx.xxx` or `xxxx.xx` or `xxxx`.

I tried the below code but instead of allowing the 5 digits, it also allows 7 and 8 digits.

```
(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{4}.\d{2}$|^\d{4}.\d{3}$)
^[0-9]{4}.([0-9]{3}|[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{5})$
```

Sample output: 1223.345 or 1324.23 or 23564

Advance Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your period needs to be escaped, or else it will be the "any character" symbol, and will allow a digit in that place.  So for that part of your regex, try:

```
/^\d{5}$|^\d{4}\.\d{2}$|^\d{4}\.\d{3}$/;
```

I'm not sure what the remainder of your regex is for, but seems outside the scope of what you're asking.

Comment: Hi pwilcox, (^\d{5}$)|(^\d{4}\.\d{2}$|^\d{4}\.\d{3}$) - this is working. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it

Comment: Changed it I think while you were commenting.  I believe it's pretty much what you have without the parentheses.  If it works for you, that's great.  Consider accepting the answer (checkmark).

Comment: You can shorten `^\d{4}\.\d{2}$|^\d{4}\.\d{3}$` to simply `^\d{4}\.\d{2,3}$`